# Perl Issue putting data into array reference (with perl URI)

Tags: arrays, perl, multidimensional-array, uri, data-dumper

**I have the following code:**

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use URI qw( );

my @insert_words = qw( HELLO );

my $newURLs;
while ( my $baseURL = <DATA>) {
   chomp $baseURL;
   my $url = URI->new($baseURL);
   my $path = $url->path();

for (@insert_words) {
  # Use package vars to communicate with /(?{})/ blocks.
  local our $insert_word = $_;
  local our @paths;
  $path =~ m{
     ^(.*[/])([^/]*)((?:[/].*)?)\z
     (?{ 
        push @paths, "$1$insert_word$2$3";
        if (length($2)) {
           push @paths, "$1$insert_word$3";
           push @paths, "$1$2$insert_word$3";
        }
     })
     (?!)
  }x;

  for (@paths) {
     $url->path($_);
     print "$url\n";  #THIS PRINTS THE CORRECT URLS I WANT IN THE ARRAY REF
     push( @{ $newURLs->{$baseURL} }, $url );  #TO PUT EACH URL INTO AN ARRAYREF BUT ITS NOT WORKING
  }
 }
}

print "\n";               #for testing only
print Dumper($newURLs);   #for testing only
print "\n";               #for testing only

__DATA__
http://www.stackoverflow.com/dog/cat/rabbit/
http://www.superuser.co.uk/dog/cat/rabbit/hamster/
http://10.15.16.17/dog/cat/rabbit/
```

**The problem I am having:**

When I do `print "$url\n";` as shown in the code above, it prints the correct urls that I want to put in the array ref, but I when I do `push( @{ $newURLs->{$baseURL} }, $url );` I get the following in the data structure:

```
$VAR1 = {
      'http://www.stackoverflow.com/dog/cat/rabbit/' => [
                                                          bless( do{\(my $o = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/dogHELLO/cat/rabbit/')}, 'URI::http' ),
                                                          $VAR1->{'http://www.stackoverflow.com/dog/cat/rabbit/'}[0],
                                                          $VAR1->{'http://www.stackoverflow.com/dog/cat/rabbit/'}[0],
                                                          $VAR1->{'http://www.stackoverflow.com/dog/cat/rabbit/'}[0],
                                                          $VAR1->{'http://www.stackoverflow.com/dog/cat/rabbit/'}[0],
                                                          $VAR1->{'http://www.stackoverflow.com/dog/cat/rabbit/'}[0],
                                                          $VAR1->{'http://www.stackoverflow.com/dog/cat/rabbit/'}[0],
                                                          $VAR1->{'http://www.stackoverflow.com/dog/cat/rabbit/'}[0],
                                                          $VAR1->{'http://www.stackoverflow.com/dog/cat/rabbit/'}[0],
                                                          $VAR1->{'http://www.stackoverflow.com/dog/cat/rabbit/'}[0]
                                                        ],
```

**When what I should be getting is the following**

```
$VAR1 = {
      'http://www.stackoverflow.com/dog/cat/rabbit/' => [
                         http://www.stackoverflow.com/dog/cat/rabbit/HELLO
                         http://www.stackoverflow.com/dog/cat/HELLOrabbit/
                         http://www.stackoverflow.com/dog/cat/HELLO/
                         http://www.stackoverflow.com/dog/cat/rabbitHELLO/
                         http://www.stackoverflow.com/dog/HELLOcat/rabbit/
                         http://www.stackoverflow.com/dog/HELLO/rabbit/
                         http://www.stackoverflow.com/dog/catHELLO/rabbit/
                         http://www.stackoverflow.com/HELLOdog/cat/rabbit/
                         http://www.stackoverflow.com/HELLO/cat/rabbit/
                         http://www.stackoverflow.com/dogHELLO/cat/rabbit/
                         ],
```

**Is it something obvious that I am overlooking or doing wrong?** Your help with this will be much appreciated, many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$url is an object. To get its stringification, you can let it interpolate:

```
 push @{ $newURLs->{$baseURL} }, "$url";
```

or call the `as_string` method:

```
push @{ $newURLs->{$baseURL} }, $url->as_string;
```

Comment: thanks, thats exactly what I was needed, also is there an easy change I can make to stop it encoding the characters in the url that need escaping so that the urls in the array ref are in a more human readable format? thanks for your help.

Comment: answer to my own question above - `URI::Escape` and `$str  = uri_unescape($safe);` , thanks

Answer (score 1):

try

```
push( @{ $newURLs->{$baseURL} }, "".$url );
```